# Escaping "=>" in twirl template

Tags: scala, twirl

I have a twirl template containing the string "=>".

The offending peice of my template is

```
@for(signal <- signalsIn ++ signalsOut) {
    @(signal.name) => odw_@(signal.name),
  }clk => clk
```

Where the output I desire is something like

```
this_signal => odw_this_signal,
that_signal => odw_that_signal,
clk => clk
```

I get the "expected start of definition" error presumably because twirl is interpreting the "=>" as syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"=>"` can be produced by `@("=>")`

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use HTML entity `&gt;` for `>` char:

```
@(signal.name) =&gt; odw_@(signal.name),
```